# MSComm Serial Error 8021 "Internal error retrieving device control block for the port"

Tags: vb6, serial-port

Occasionally we get this error when communicating between my motion control software and a plasma cutting torch. What the serial link is being used for is a one time setup of cutting information before the cutting begins. I am using VB6 and MSComm for this.

I know the port itself has lunched because after it occurs other serial comm software (diagnostics, etc) can't access the port either. I would like to understand what MSCOmm is doing when it received this error so I can find a better hardware solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different OCX

[www.comm32.com](http://www.comm32.com/) has a control that mimics mscomm but has many improvements

Answer (score 1):

`Mscomm32.ocx` is still [fully supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx) by Microsoft. You could ask their support people to help. If you have an MSDN subscription, you may be entitled to free support incidents.

Apologies if you'd already thought of that, I hope someone else can give you a direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and that is why entered into this forum. After going deeper into the problem of communication getting lost, found the intermitence belongs to my USB-RS232 converter module. Mainly because it is working controling external hardware it gets exposed to electrical noise causing a disruption to the USB-RS232 module. It gets resolved by unplugging it and putting it back, or by turning off the whole system. Make sure your software issue is not a hardare problem

Comment: The OP was asking about MSComm and what it is doing when the error occurs.